# Incremental rotation that snaps in place

Tags: mechanisms, mechanical

I'm developing a board game and it needs a mechanism of incremental rotation in which the rotated object will snap to one of five possible angles. I have been trying to search for examples of mechanisms that snap in increments when rotated but I don't seem to know the correct terminology.

The rotating shaft would be a five sided polygon (pentagon) as in the picture:

[image: Design]

What kind of design might work in this case so that after the player rotates the shaft, it always snaps into a "straight" angle so that one of the five surfaces of the polygon is facing straight up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vee-shaped block spung up against the underside of the pentagonal shaft would do the trick.

[image]

*Figure 1. A badly dimensioned snap.*

You'd need a lot longer on the "spring" section of this to allow enough flexibility.

A search for [3D printed detent](https://www.google.com/search?q=3d+printed+detent&tbm=isch) should give plenty of ideas.

Comment: Thank you, very cool idea!

Answer (score 1):

A spring loaded button and detent.

Comment: Thanks. Detent was a good search term. I found this 3d-printable object with an interesting spring/detent mechanic: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2706672/files Especially file called CipherRing-Top.stl.